# We are stuck on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 (macpro version) how do we get beyond Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 for iOS development on iOS 6

Tags: xcode

how can you help to get ios 6 sdk or get 4.2 for snow leopard.because ive been working on this for a long time but this is beond what i know
Thank You

Comment: You actually need to compile against iOS 7 now, or Apple will reject your app.

Comment: sorry i don't entirely get what you mean and if you mean that i can only make apps on ios 7 then i can just put the app so you can download it off my website like with emo4ios or whatever its called